# Pushforward of covering maps

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, covering-spaces, kan-extension

Let $A,B$ be sufficiently connected spaces so as to have the category of coverings equivalent to the category of representations of the fundamental groupoid.

Given a covering map of $A$ and a continuous map $A\overset{f}{\to} B$, we may pass to the associated representation of $\pi_1A$ and take its left Kan extension along $\pi_1A\overset{\pi_1f}{\to} \pi_1B$ to obtain a representation of $\pi_1B$. Finally, we may integrate it into a covering map of $B$. This defines the *pushforward of a covering map along a continuous map*.

**Question.** How to calculate - or at least anticipate - this pushforward?

For instance, what is the pushforward of the $n$-fold cover of $\mathbb S^1$ along the $k$-fold cover of $\mathbb S^1$?

I'm trying to use the formula for pointwise Kan extensions, but I'm struggling. At least for $f:\bf 1\to \mathbb S^1$, the fibers of the pushforward of the identity on the point seem to be $\mathbb Z$, but even in this case I'm struggling to calculate the parallel transport.

Comment: just induce up: $V \mapsto \uparrow_{\pi_1A}^{\pi_1B}V$. To check it's correct, notice you're describing a left adjoint to pulling back {coverings of B}--->{coverings of A}. Under the identification of coverings with representations, it's easy to see this is restriction, so the left adjoint has no choice but to be induction.

Comment: @DylanWilson I agree with everything you've written, but I don't know how to calculate that tensor product either. I don't even know the covering given by the pushforward of an identity map.

Comment: the pushforward along the identity will be the identity functor... pushing forward along inclusion of a point will send a cover to copies of the universal cover... etc. in general, write your pi_1A-set as a coproduct of stuff like pi_1A/H and send each of those to \pi_B/f(H) where f:\pi_1A-->pi_1B.

Comment: @DylanWilson I asked about the pushforward of the identity cover, not along the identity map. Why does pushing along a point take covers to copies of the universal cover? (Thanks for your patience!)

Comment: Just apply the general procedure above! In this case the identity map is the cover pi_1A/pi_1A so it goes to the cover associated to pi_1B/f(pi_1A). Again, to answer the next question you ask just apply the general procedure.

Comment: @DylanWilson "just"! Strong words...

Comment: Surely this is elementary if you stop using fancy words like "left  Kan extension"!?  It's really a lot easier to work with fundamental groups than fundamental groupoids. (I look forward to Ronnie Brown's reply...)  Working componentwise, you may as well assume everything is connected.  If $A'\to A$ is a covering map and $f:A\to B$ is continuous, then the only reasonable "push forward" of $A'$ is the cover of $B$ corresponding to the subgroup $f_*(\pi_1A')$; i.e., the quotient of the universal cover of $B$ by $f_*(\pi_1A')$. (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) In the case of circles that you ask about, the $n$-fold cover of $S^1$ corresponds to the subgroup $\langle n\rangle$, and the $k$-fold cover includes $\mathbb{Z}$ as $\langle k\rangle$ into $\mathbb{Z}$, so the pushforward corresponds to the subgroup $\langle nk\rangle$. So it's the $nk$-fold cover.  And, as already mentioned, if $f$ is inclusion of a point, the corresponding subgroup is trivial and so the corresponding cover is the univeral cover.